# Memory usage of pivot_longer run on small object

Tags: r, memory, dplyr

I'm working on a dataframe consisting of 528 column and 2,643,246 rows. Eight of these are character-variables, and the rest integers. In total, this adds up to 11.35 GiB of data, with my available RAM being at 164 GiB.

I now wanted to run a `pivot_longer` on said dataframe, having one row for each column + two ID variables (year and institution). There are a total of 671,370 institutions over 76 years.
So atm the data are structured such as this:

| Institution | Year | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 |

Where I would like to change it so the structure becomes:

| Institution | Year | G | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | X | 2 |
| A | 1 | Y | 1 |
| A | 1 | Z | 3 |
| A | 2 | X | 3 |
| A | 2 | Y | 1 |
| A | 2 | Z | 4 |
| B | 1 | X | 3 |
| B | 1 | Y | 4 |
| B | 1 | Z | 2 |
| B | 2 | X | 5 |
| B | 2 | Y | 3 |
| B | 2 | Z | 2 |

To achieve this I attempted the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
Df <- Df  %>% pivot_longer(17:527,
           names_to = "G",
           values_to = "N"
           )
```

When running this on a small sample-data I manage to achieve the expected results, however when attempting to do the same on the whole dataset I quickly run out of memory. From the object using 11 GiB of memory, it quickly increased to above 150 GiB before returning a "cannot allocate vector of size x Gb" error.

Since I haven't *added* any data, I can't quite understand where the extra memory usage is coming from. What I wonder therefore is what creates this increase, and whether there is a more efficient way to solve this problem through some other code.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this size data, `reshape2` or `data.table`'s pivoting will likely be more memory-efficient than `tidyr`'s. On a smaller 800MB sample, `reshape2::melt` requires around 2.6x as much memory as the original data, `data.table::melt` requires around 3.6x as much, while the `tidyr::pivot_longer` approach in this case needs about 12x as much memory, and is about 20x slower.

EDIT: Upon review of the warnings, I realized that my earlier draft was actually using `reshape2` under the hood when I called `data.table::melt`, since I was feeding it a tibble. Added explicit `data.table::melt` solution that includes a translation of the data to data.table. For this data, `reshape2::melt` seems to be faster and more memory efficient.

##### Sample data

```
n1 = as.integer(2E8/26)
set.seed(42)
data_long <- data.frame(Institution = 1:n1,
                        G = rep(letters, each = n1),
                        Z = rpois(26*n1, 10))
data_wide <- data_long %>% pivot_wider(names_from = G, values_from = Z)
```

##### Benchmarks

```
bench::mark(
  tidyr::pivot_longer(data_wide, -1),
  reshape2::melt(data_wide, id.vars = 1),
  data.table::melt(data.table::as.data.table(data_wide), id.vars = 1),
  check = FALSE,
  iterations = 10
)

# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression                                                               min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>                                                          <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 tidyr::pivot_longer(data_wide, -1)                                    26.77s   37.38s    0.0269   10.52GB   0.0538    10    20       6.2m
2 reshape2::melt(data_wide, id.vars = 1)                                 1.25s    1.73s    0.519     2.23GB   0.156     10     3      19.3s
3 data.table::melt(data.table::as.data.table(data_wide), id.vars = 1)    1.82s    2.41s    0.332     3.01GB   0.232     10     7      30.1s
# … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: The reshape2::melt command worked perfectly! Just in case anyone reads this in the future, I had to remove all id-variables but one to get it work. With these included I ended up with the same issue, without however, it only used 4x as much memory to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have no ways to test the code on your data, but here is one idea.

The idea is to conduct the wide to long transformation for a chunk of rows one at a time, store the outcome in a list. In the end, combine the list to the final data frame. Hopefully this reduces the memory usage.

If not working, try to see if `melt` from `data.table` can convert the data more efficiently.

One other idea that could be helpful. Perhaps subset the `Df` by removing column 1 to 16 before the wide to long transformation, just keep an `ID` column. You can join column 1 to 16 back to the converted data frame later.

```
library(tidyverse)

Df_list <- list()

Institution <- unique(DF$Institution)

for (i in Institution){
  Df_temp <- Df  %>%
    filter(Institution %in% i) %>%
    pivot_longer(17:527, names_to = "G", values_to = "N")
  Df_list[[i]] <- Df_temp
}

Df <- bind_rows(Df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you!  It seems like the solution might possibly have worked, however, after 16 hours I ended up stopping the process. At that point it had completed 19 iterations.